# try_cast and cast differing results. The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, try-cast

I have a two SQL 2017 databases.

Database 1 contains table(a) with a column of `datatype "date"`

Database 2 contains table(b) with a column of `datatype "datetime"`

I'm doing a basic insert statement from `"table a"` into `"table b"` using

```
SELECT CAST(si.InceptionDate AS datetime).
```

**This is currently failing with the error**

```
"The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."
```

If I change the insert statement to

`SELECT TRY_CAST(si.InceptionDate AS datetime)` this now works.  This makes sense in theory however the datetime column in "table b" doesn't contain any NULLs and isn't missing any records from `"table a"`.  How can `try_cast` manage to successfully change the datatype but cast can't?

I think this has something to do with the data being selected from "table a" because I created a dummy table with the "date" data type on database 2 and inserted into this first before inserting insert "table b" and this works no problem.

Can anyone think of a reason for this???  It has me stumped :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your query is more complicated than you are showing.

My guess is that some of the values would result in conversion errors *but these rows are filtered out of the final result*.  SQL Server has a habit of pushing expressions before filtering clauses.  Once consequence is that errors on rows that would be filtered out cause the query to fail.

Comment: Interesting...haven't come across this before but it feels like this could be the reason.  I have some inner joins on the select query and the field being inserted is from a joined table. From doing a bit more fiddling if I ditch the insert and do a select with the CAST statement it returns the whole dataset no problem.  
If I then do ORDER BY CAST(si.InceptionDate as datetime) it fails with the same error message

Comment: @MarkDungey . . . Just use `try_cast()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that could be contributing here, and without any sample data, I can only guess which (though it could be both).

Firstly, let's address the 2 functions you have, `TRY_CAST` and `CAST`. `TRY_CAST` cannot return the error you have; if the conversion fails then `NULL` is returned. That is by design and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will have told you that.

Next, you have 2 different data types, `datetime` and `date`. `datetime` is an older data type and is suseptical to problems based on the `LOGIN's` `LANGUAGE` setting. Specifically, for `datetime` (and `smalldatetime`) the format `yyyy-MM-dd` is **not** unambiguous. This can be reproed with the below:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American

SELECT CAST('2021-01-13' AS datetime); --Works
GO

SET LANGUAGE BRITISH; --English; we speak ENGLISH in England...

SELECT CAST('2021-01-13' AS datetime); --Fails
GO
```

This doesn't happen with `date`:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American

SELECT CAST('2021-01-13' AS date); --Works
GO

SET LANGUAGE BRITISH; --English; we speak ENGLISH in England...

SELECT CAST('2021-01-13' AS date); --Works
GO
```

Again, as we have no sample, then either 1 or both of these factors are contributing.